# Constructing Isomorphism between finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Consider $\mathbb{F}_3(\alpha)$ where $\alpha^3 - \alpha +1 = 0$ and $\mathbb{F}_3(\beta)$ where $\beta^3 - \beta^2 +1 =0$.

I know these two fields are isomorphic but I have difficulty buliding an isomorphism between them.

I know I have to determine where $\alpha$ is mapped to under the isomorphism map but I can't figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, clearly $\alpha$ has to be mapped to something which is a root of $x^3-x+1=0$.

Comment: And there are only 27 elements of $\mathbb F_3(\beta)$ to check ...

Comment: Hi Chris, Suppose $\phi: \mathbb{F}_3(\alpha)\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_3(\beta)$ is the isomorphism. Then $\phi (\alpha)$ must be an expression in terms of $\beta$. Am I thinking about this the right way?!!?

Comment: I removed the "extraordinary isomorphisms" tag because for one, I feel like this is a rather ordinary isomorphism, and for two, I've never even heard that term and don't feel like it merits its own tag at this point. If someone feels this was hasty, please let me know.

Answer (score 9):

One way to do it is just to slug through it:

An isomorphism $\mathbb{F}_3(\alpha)\to\mathbb{F}_3(\beta)$ is completely determined by the image of $\alpha$; and, as you note in comments, the image of $\alpha$ must be of the form $a\beta^2 + b\beta + c$, with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{F}_3$. Moreover, the image of $\alpha$ must satisfy $\alpha^3 = \alpha - 1$; that is, you want to find $a,b,c$ such that
$$(a\beta^2 + b\beta + c)^3 = a\beta^2 + b\beta + c-1.$$
So you can just expand the left hand side, using $\beta^3 = \beta^2-1$, and figure out the coefficients. We have:
$$\begin{align*}
\beta^3 &= \beta^2 - 1\\
\beta^4 &= \beta^3-\beta\\
&= \beta^2 - \beta - 1\\
\beta^6 &= (\beta^3)^2
= \beta^4 - 2\beta^2 + 1\\
&= \beta^2 - \beta - 1 -2\beta^2 + 1\\
&= -\beta^2 - \beta.
\end{align*}$$
And so, since we are in characteristic $3$,
$$\begin{align*}
(a\beta^2 + b\beta + c)^3 &= a^3\beta^6 + b^3\beta^3 + c^3\\
&= a^3(-\beta^2-\beta) + b^3(\beta^2-1) + c^3\\
&= (b^3-a^3)\beta^2 + (-a^3)\beta + c^3-b^3\\
&= a\beta^2 + b\beta + c - 1.
\end{align*}$$
So we need to solve the equations
$$\begin{align*}
b^3-a^3 &= a\\
-a^3 &= b\\
c^3 -b^3&= c-1.
\end{align*}$$
Since $a,b,c\in\mathbb{F}_3$, where $x^3=x$ for all $x$, we get
$$\begin{align*}
b-a &= a\\
-a&=b\\
c-b&= c-1
\end{align*}$$
The first two equations both give $b=-a$; the last equation gives $b=1$. So $a=-1$, $b=1$, and $c$ is free (this gives the three roots of the polynomial). That is, $f(\alpha)$ can be any of $-\beta^2+\beta$, $-\beta^2+\beta+1$, $-\beta^2+\beta-1$. You can verify they all work.

Answer (score 7):

From $\beta^3 - \beta^2 + 1 = 0$, we get $1 - \beta^{-1} + \beta^{-3} = 0$, and
since $\alpha^3 - \alpha + 1 = 0$, we can map $\alpha$ to $\beta^{-1}$ to get 
the desired isomorphism.  Of course, from $\beta^3 - \beta^2 + 1 = 0$ we get 
$\beta^2 - \beta + \beta^{-1} = 0$, that is, $\beta^{-1} = -\beta^2 + \beta$.
In other words, we can take $f(\alpha) = -\beta^2 + \beta$ exactly as Arturo
Magidin found.

**Edit: Added note** We could instead have chosen to map $\alpha$ to the *conjugates* $\beta^{-3}$ or $\beta^{-3^2}$ of $\beta^{-1}$ where we
have that
$$\beta^{-3} = \beta^{-1} - 1 = -\beta^2 + \beta - 1,$$ and 
$$\beta^{-3^2} = (\beta^{-1} - 1)^3 = \beta^{-3}-1 = -\beta^2 + \beta + 1$$which are the other two possible images of $\alpha$ given in Arturo's answer. 
As in implied in Jyrki Lahtonen's comment, a simpler derivation is 
possible in this case because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of reciprocal
polynomials.

Comment: +1: Stare at the minimal polynomials. Observe that they are each others reciprocal polynomials....