# Isomorphism between finite fields adjoining a root

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $p(x)=x^3+x^2+1$ and $q(x)=x^3+x+1$ be polynomials over the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $p(x)$ and $\beta$ be a root of $q(x)$. Now let $K=\mathbb{Z}_2(\alpha)$ and $F=\mathbb{Z}_2(\beta)$. I am asked to find an explicit isomorphism $\phi: K \rightarrow F$.

I know that since $p(\alpha)=0$ and $q(\beta)=0$ then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic over $\mathbb{Z}_2$. I'm rather stuck after this point, and my other problems are somewhat similar to this one, so if there is a key fact that I'm missing then it might allow me to solve the others.

Comment: So, $p$ and $q$ are both irreducible and hence $K$ and $F$ are both degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$. So you just have to show that $b$ is contained in $K$ or that $a$ is contained in $F$.

Comment: I can't see how. Also, how does this give me my isomorphism?

Comment: See the answers to [this closely related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/108717/15941) which will tell you how to construct an _explicit_ isomorphism between $\mathbb F_3(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb F_3(\beta)$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of _reciprocal_ polynomials, just as they are in this case of extensions of $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: Okay, after a long computation that won't fit here, I get $\phi(\alpha)=-\beta^2+1$.

Comment: Dilip's right. You can select $\alpha=1/\beta=\beta^2+1$. Meaning that you are right, too! The sun shines and all that...

Comment: Ok, so since $\beta^3+\beta+1=0$, then $1+\beta^{-2}+\beta^{-3}=0$. Now, since $\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1=0$, I can map $\alpha$ to $\beta^{-1}$. Also, $\beta^2+1+\beta^{-1}=0 \Rightarrow \beta^{-1}=-1-\beta^2$. Thus, $\phi(\alpha)=-1-\beta^2$. Is this right?

Comment: That's correct. Well done. BTW, you can forget about the minus signs. In characteristic two you never make a sign error!