# What is the isomorphism between the fields $(Z_2[x]^{<3},+_{x^3+x^2+1},\times_{x^3+x^2+1})$ and $(Z_2[x]^{<3},+_{x^3+x+1},\times_{x^3+x+1})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, group-isomorphism

They are both Galois fields of order 8.
I'm not exactly sure what the question means - how does one determine/describe an isomorphism?

Comment: This is essentially solved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/787299/11619).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are terrible notations for the fields $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+1)$ and $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)$. Since we have $(x+1)^3+(x+1)+1=x^3+x^2+1$, the isomorphism $\mathbb{F}_2[x] \to \mathbb{F}_2[x]$, $x \mapsto x+1$ maps $(x^3+x+1)$ onto $(x^3+x^2+1)$, so that it induces an isomorphism $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^3+x+1) \to \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+1)$.

Comment: Can you explain why they are bad notations? It's what our professor seems to use.

Comment: Because it is clumsy and impractical to use systems of representatives (here polynomials of degree $< 3$), and to ignore the useful relationship to quotient rings. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring

Comment: I guess it must be because we haven't seen quotient rings yet. Thanks for your time !