# Procedure to find explicit isomorphisms between two quotient rings: $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + 1) \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + \alpha^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields, ring-isomorphism

Given a ring homomorphism, I'm pretty comfortable with proving whether or not it is an isomorphism. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to systematically coming up with a ring homomorphism in the first place in order to show isomorphism. A specific example is 
$$
\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + 1) \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + \alpha^2)
$$
$(x^2 + 1), (x^2 + \alpha^2)$ are the principle ideals generated by $x^2 + 1, x^2 + \alpha^2$, respectively. My understanding of the (first) quotient ring in this example is the set $\{f(x) + (x^2+1) \;\vert\; f(x) = ax + b, a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ (please let me know if I'm wrong here).

A ring homomorphism would map the identity $1 + (x^2 + 1)$ to $1 + (x^2 + \alpha^2)$, and some $ax +b + (x^2 + 1)$ to some $a'x + b' + (x^2 + \alpha^2)$. (correct?)

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778202/isomorphism-between-two-polynomial-quotient-fields) seems to answer what I'm trying to do, but I don't understand the "abstract root" and why $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]/(x^2 + 1) = \mathbb{Z}_{11}[a]$ in his example, and I don't have enough rep points to comment. Could anyone show me how to do this? You don't need to use my specific example, once I understand it I'll probably able to do it myself. Thanks!

Comment: In this case, the obvious isomorphism is $x\mapsto x/\alpha$.

Comment: More generally, given a field, $k$, a homomorphism $f:k[x]\to k[x]$ is completely determined by the field homomorphism $f\vert_{k}:k\to k$, and where it sends $x$. The homomorphism will be an isomorphism if and only if $f\vert_k$ is an isomorphism and $f(x)=ax+b$ for some $a\neq 0$. With this knowledge, you can usually figure out what an isomorphism between two polynomial rings (or their quotients) would be if there is one.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Just one more question, when you said $x \mapsto x/\alpha$, is it just that (we'd be working with $\mathbb{R}[x]$), or is it actually $x + (x^2+1) \mapsto x/\alpha + (x^2 + \alpha^2)$?

Comment: That's right, I actually meant $x+(x^2+1)\mapsto x/\alpha+(x^2+\alpha^2)$. It's common to drop the coset notation in quotients of polynomial rings and simply write polynomials. Additionally, a good way to think about this is that you are setting $x^2+1=0$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ since indeed $x^2+1+(x^2+1)=0+(x^2+1)$. In other words, everything which is quotiented out is now $0$.

Comment: Thanks very much!