# Spesicif Isomorphism between Finite Field Extension

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields

Notice that, $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$/$<x^2+x+1>$ and $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$/$<x^2+2>$ are both finite field with the same 25 elements, thus must be isomorphic. Yes, there is general theorem stated that every finite field with the same order $p^n$ where $p$ is prime, then they are isomorphic. But i want the specific isomorphism between those of two.

Let $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$/$<x^2+x+1>=\mathbb{Z}_5[\alpha]$ where $\alpha$ is an abstract root of $x^2+x+1$ and $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$/$<x^2+2> =\mathbb{Z}_5[\beta]$ where $\beta$ is an abstract root of $x^2+2$.

Then, using the step in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108717/constructing-isomorphism-between-finite-field), answer by Arturo Magidin. I got $i : \mathbb{Z}_5[\alpha] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_5[\beta]$ where $i(\alpha)=\beta+1$.

Now, what im questioning is, how to show that $i$ satisfies homomorphism? And, i think i got problem to show cause im not understanding well what does an abstract root that i mentioned above.

Thus, once i understand to show the homomorphism, the rest is to show the kernel is trivial, hence it is injective, since both size is 25, then they must be surjective too.

Comment: A homomorphism $i$ such that $i(\alpha)=\beta+1$ exists if and only if $\alpha$ and $\beta+1$ have the same minimal polynomial. Do they? Another way here would be to use the quadratic formula. The discriminant of $x^2+x+1$ is $\Delta=1^2-4\cdot1\cdot=-3$, so you can write the zeros of $x^2+x+1$ using a square root of $-3$. Can you find a square root of $-3$ in $\Bbb{Z}_5[\beta]$?

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $\beta +1$ is $x^2+3x+3$. I think you want $i(\alpha) = \beta+2$.

Comment: sorry, the right one is $\beta +2$, and the minimal polynomial of $\beta+2$ is $x^2+x+1$, right? and then the next step after finding the minpol?

Comment: You are done now because $Z_5(\beta) = Z_5(\beta+2) = Z_5(x)/(x^2+x+1) = Z_5(\alpha)$.

Comment: I get it, would you mind to write it in answer column so that this question can be checked as answered one? Thank you! so much!