# Find a root in a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have $f(x) = x^3 - x + 1$ and $g(x) = x^3 - x - 1$, which are irreducible in $\mathbb Z_{3}[x]$, and the finite fields $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x] /(f(x)) $ and $ \mathbb{Z}_{3}[x] /(g(x))$. I'm trying to prove that there is a root for $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x] /(g(x))$, but I don't seem to find it.

My strategy has been trying to find a root of the form $a + b\beta + c\beta^{2}$, with $a,b,c \in \{0,1,2\}$ knowing that $\beta$ is the root of $g(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x] /(g(x))$, but I have failed so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: The finite fields $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x] /(f(x)) $ and $ \mathbb{Z}_{3}[x] /(g(x))$ are isomorphic.

Comment: That's what I want to prove at the end, but I still don't know that they're isomorphic in my course.

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/108717/11619) for another recurring trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*: Compute $f(-\beta)$.

Or systematically: $0=f(a + b\beta + c\beta^{2})=\cdots=2c\beta+(b+c+1)$ implies $b=-1$ and $c=0$. Taking $a=0$ gives that $-\beta$ is a root of $f$.

The key point here is that $(a + b\beta + c\beta^{2})^3=a^3 + b^3\beta^3 + c^3\beta^{6})=a + b\beta^3 + c\beta^{6}$ because the characteristic is $3$ and also $u^3=u$ for $u \in \mathbb{Z}_{3}$. Now take the remainder mod $\beta^3-\beta-1$ using polynomial division.

This argument actually shows that the roots of $f$ are $-\beta$, $1-\beta$, $-1-\beta$.

Comment: I think that works, thank you very much!